# How to use a pre-trained language model correctly?

Tags: python, nlp, allennlp

I'm trying to use a Huggingface pretrained model "GPT2dialog" as a encoder for sentences,But the textindexer confused me.
In detail ,I can run a unittest for dataset_reader with a pretrained indexer normally,when use the train command to train the model caused a Bug:

```
File "/home/lee/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/common/lazy.py", line 54, in constructor_to_use
    return constructor.from_params(Params({}), **kwargs)  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "/home/lee/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py", line 604, in from_params
    **extras,
  File "/home/lee/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py", line 634, in from_params
    return constructor_to_call(**kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/lee/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/data/vocabulary.py", line 310, in from_instances
    instance.count_vocab_items(namespace_token_counts)
  File "/home/lee/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/data/instance.py", line 60, in count_vocab_items
    field.count_vocab_items(counter)
  File "/home/lee/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/data/fields/text_field.py", line 78, in count_vocab_items
    for indexer in self.token_indexers.values():
AttributeError: 'PretrainedTransformerIndexer' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Here is my dataset_reader code.

```
class MultiWozDatasetReader(DatasetReader):
 def __init__(self,
              lazy:bool = False,
              tokenizer: Tokenizer = None,
              tokenindexer:Dict[str, TokenIndexer] = None
              ) -> None:
     super().__init__(lazy)
     self._tokenizer = tokenizer or WhitespaceTokenizer()
     self._tokenindexer = PretrainedTransformerIndexer("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")

 @overrides
 def read(self, file_path: str):
     logger.warn("call read")
     with open(file_path, 'r') as data_file:
         dialogs = json.load(data_file)
         for dialog in dialogs:
             dialogue = dialog["dialogue"]
             for turn_num in range(len(dialogue)):
                 dia_single_turn = dialogue[turn_num]
                 sys_utt = dia_single_turn["system_transcript"]
                 user_utt = dia_single_turn["transcript"]
                 state_category = dia_single_turn["state_category"]
                 span_info = dia_single_turn["span"]

                 yield self.text_to_instance(sys_utt, user_utt, state_category, span_info)
 @overrides
 def text_to_instance(self, sys_utt, user_utt, state_catgory, span_info):

     tokenized_sys_utt = self._tokenizer.tokenize(sys_utt)
     tokenized_user_utt = self._tokenizer.tokenize(user_utt)
     tokenized_span_info = self._tokenizer.tokenize(span_info)

     tokenized_classifier_input = self._tokenizer.tokenize("[CLS] "+ sys_utt + " [SEP] "+ user_utt)

     sys_utt_field = TextField(tokenized_sys_utt, self._tokenindexer)
     user_utt_field = TextField(tokenized_user_utt, self._tokenindexer)
     classifier_filed = TextField(tokenized_classifier_input, self._tokenindexer)
     span_field = TextField(tokenized_span_info, self._tokenindexer)
     fields = {"sys_utt": sys_utt_field,"user_utt":user_utt_field,"classifier_input":classifier_filed,"span":span_field}
     fields['label']=LabelField(state_catgory)
     return Instance(fields)
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: My guess is that there is something wrong with your code. But we can only tell you what is wrong with the code, if you show us the code.

Comment: I have added dataset_reader's code, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token_indexer needs to be a dictionary. It can be set as follows:

`self._token_indexers = {"tokens": PretrainedTransformerIndexer("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it sloved my problem!

Comment: There is another error occurs, how can i use this token_indexers  in my model ?